# Metabase Content Security Policy - Load Balancer, CloudFront, Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, content-security-policy, metabase

I currently have a Metabase EC2 instance running on AWS that is being routed through a Load Balancer and then connected to a CloudFront distribution.

When accessing the Load Balancer directly (i.e. `load-balancer-12345.region.elb.amazonaws.com:port`) everything works fine, but when accessing it through Route53 / CloudFront on `metabase.domain.co.uk` the site loads but with the error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").
```

I've added everything that is required on CloudFront, even adding the custom `Content-Security-Policy` with all `default-src 'self';` but I still get this error.

Metabase version: `v0.34.2`

Can anyone offer any guidance? I can give more information if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my post would be helpful. because when i configure with cloudfront for discourse without docker, i was trouble with these kind of problem. check this post buddy. https://venz.ai/configure-aws-cloudfront-in-discourse-without-docker/

would be great ! just follow the step 4 and 5 in this post for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: https://discourse.metabase.com/t/content-security-policy-load-balancer-cloudfront-route53/9515

Metabase does not work with proxies that modify the content - have a look at this:
https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting-guide/proxies.md 1